# Ldap Search query in parent child relation

Tags: ldap, ldap-query, apacheds

I want to get/check **userCertificate** attribute (it belongs to parent attribute set) from a child attribute(**mail**) match. Structure of ldap entry is

```
DN: dc=abc,dc=com
    |
    DN: uid=[ID],dc=abc,dc=com (this entry attribute set contains userCertificate )
        |
        DN: ou=Group,uid=[ID],dc=abc,dc=com
            |
            DN: ou=user,ou=Group,uid=[ID],dc=abc,dc=com (this entry contains email attribute)
```

This structure is already defined in customer specification.

1. How can i get/check userCertificate in LDAP search query with **mail** only attribute in hand?
2. Is it possible in one search Query?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this in a single query.
You will need to search for the entry with the mail attribute, then parse the DN of the entry to compute the parent, parent DN, which you can then read or search (based on the presence of the userCertificate for example).